# T-SQL: Joining on two separate fields based on specific criteria in a query

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

I have a query in which I am trying to get additional fields from another table through a join field that I manually create. The issue is when the field I create is null, then I want to use another field to join on. I am not sure how to do that without getting duplicate results. I tried a UNION query, but that just displays everything where the values are null when the manually created field value is null. Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    BU = m.BU,
    BUFBA = m.BUFBA,
    a.CostCenter,
    Delegate = m.Delegate,
    a.DistrictLookup,
    PCOwner = m.PCOwner,
    a.PGr,
    a.POrg,
    PrimaryContact = m.PrimaryContact,
    WarehouseManager = m.WarehouseManager,
    Zone = m.Zone,
    ZoneFBA = m.ZoneFBA
FROM
(SELECT
    e.CostCenter,
    e.District,
    DistrictLookup =
        CASE
            WHEN e.PGr IN ('N01','BQE','BQA') THEN 'GSS'
            WHEN e.PGr = 'BQB' THEN 'BG'
            WHEN e.PGr = 'BQF' THEN 'FP'
            ELSE e.District
            END,
    e.PGr,
    e.POrg
 FROM dbo.E1P e (NOLOCK)        
        WHERE
            e.CoCd = '4433'
    ) a

LEFT JOIN dbo.Mapping m (NOLOCK) ON m.District = a.DistrictLookup
```

When the DistrictLookup field is NULL, I need a different join to occur so that the additional fields populate. That join would be:

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.Mapping m (NOLOCK) ON m.CostCenter = a.CostCenter
```

How can I write in this second join and not get duplicate results? This is a separate join on different fields and I think it differs from the other methods of doing a conditional join.  If it, can someone please explain how to implement that logic into my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after...

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.Mapping m (NOLOCK) 
   ON (a.DistrictLookup IS NOT NULL AND m.District = a.DistrictLookup)
   OR (a.DistrictLookup IS NULL AND m.CostCenter = a.CostCenter)
```